# avformat_write_header fails with error "invalid argument

Tags: c, ffmpeg, libavformat

I'm trying to write a chunk of a mp4 file to a .ts file, which does not yet exist. 
So first I create AVFormatContext this way:

```
AVOutputFormat *oformat = av_guess_format( NULL,
                                           "mpegts",
                                           "video/x-mpegts" );
AVFormatContext * outFormatContext = NULL;
avformat_alloc_output_context2( &outFormatContext, oformat, NULL, dst_file)
```

outFormatContext is created and outFormatContext->oformat is set to oformat. Then I open I/O context on outFormatContext:

```
avio_open(&outFormatContext->pb, dst_file, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE)
avformat_write_header( outFormatContext, NULL );
```

according to [this](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__encoding.html#ga78d4e734fecb1d2385536e6dd5b7b9f5) this is enough for avformat_write_header to work but it fails with error "invalid argument".

What else needs to be done to successfully write the header?

Comment: You do call `avio_open()` before `avformat_write_header()` and after `avformat_alloc_output_context2()` don't you? And does your real code (error)check the values returned by those `av*()` functions you call?

Comment: Does `av_guess_format()` return something different from `NULL`?

Comment: I fixed the sequence, avformat_write_header goes last of course. And yes, av_guess_format returns not NULL, and avformat_alloc_output_context2 returns successfully.

Comment: And what does `avio_open()` return?

Comment: avio_open() returns zero. Only avformat_write_header is failing.

Comment: You must add at least one audio or video stream

Comment: @kopalvich Did you solved the issue? What was the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Although it's a little bit late, I hope it would be helpful.
Here is my way to call `avformat_write_header`, you should have a stream provided to write the header.

```
AVFormatContext* pOutFormatContext;
AVOutputFormat* avOutputFormat;
if ((avOutputFormat = av_guess_format(NULL, "mp4", "video/mp4")) == NULL) {
    cerr << "Could not guess output format" << endl;
    return -1;
}

avformat_alloc_output_context2(&pOutFormatContext,
                               av_guess_format("mp4", NULL, "video/mp4"), NULL, NULL);
if (pOutFormatContext == NULL) {
    cerr << "Could not allocate output context" << endl;
    return -1;
}

for (int i = 0; i < avFormatContext->nb_streams; i++) {
    AVStream* inAVStream = avFormatContext->streams[i];
    AVStream* outAVStream = avformat_new_stream(pOutFormatContext, inAVStream->codec->codec);
    if (avcodec_copy_context(outAVStream->codec, inAVStream->codec) < 0) {
        cerr << "Failed to copy codec context" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    outAVStream->codec->codec_tag = 0;
    if (pOutFormatContext->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER) {
        outAVStream->codec->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
    }
}

avio_open(&pOutFormatContext->pb, "test.mp4", AVIO_FLAG_READ_WRITE);
if (pOutFormatContext->pb == NULL) {
    cerr << "Could not open for writing" << endl;
    return -1;
}
if (avformat_write_header(pOutFormatContext, NULL) != 0) {
    cerr << "Could not write header" << endl;
    return -1;
}
```